# How to Validate and Compare Data against the Database in DetailView - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-database

I have a ChallengeDetailView which shows the details of a challenge like a blog post. I also have a form field on the same page and it supposed to get an answer of a challenge, and compare it to the database. So far here is what I did;

```
class ChallengeDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Challenge

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ChallengeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = FlagForm
        return context
```

```
from django import forms


class FlagForm(forms.Form):
    flag = forms.CharField(label='Challenge Flag',required=True)
```

```
class FlagFormView(FormView):
    form_class = FlagForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('challenge-detail')
```

I try to implement a simple logic like the following;

```
def get_flag(self, request):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        form = FlagForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            flag = form.cleaned_data.get('flag')
            if flag == Challenge.flag:
                return messages.success("You found the flag!")
    else:
        return FlagForm()
```

I tried to include this in form_valid() method but couldn't make it work in the ChallengeDetailView. I'm open to any kind of suggestions. I'm coming from a Symfony background and pretty new to Django.

Comment: can you add your **`FlagForm`** class?

Comment: Sorry I missed it. Updated the question. Thanks for the warning. @JPG

Comment: first of all, you can use [Django's **`ModelForm`** class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) here, which more compatible with models. So, I would suggest to re-write the **`FlagForm`** with **ModelForm** and write appropriate [validation functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform) in the Form class itself.

Comment: Followed the documentation you provided, but now when I send the form I get a 405 error. I think that's because POST methods are not allowed in a detailview. Is there right way to enable POST methods on detailview or it's against the good practices?  @JPG

Comment: Yeah..you are right. You need to use `UpdateView` along with the DetailView.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to figure it out. 
I created a regular form in forms.py

```
from django import forms

class FlagForm(forms.Form):
    flag = forms.CharField()
```

In views.py I have a detail view and form view with SingleObjectMixin to work on the current post.

```
class ChallengeDisplay(DetailView):
model = Challenge

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = FlagForm()
    return context
```

Form view with SingleObjectMixin;

```
class ChallengeFormEntry(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'ctf/challenge_detail.html'
    form_class = FlagForm
    model = Challenge

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FlagForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            flag = form.cleaned_data.get('flag')
            if self.get_object().flag == flag:
                messages.success(request, 'good job!')
            else: messages.warning(request, 'Try again!')
    form = FlagForm()
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('challenge-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().pk, 'slug':self.get_object().slug})
```